# ¿Cómo eliminar la leyenda de la derecha de mi ggplot+ geom_bar y ordenar el eje x según me interesa en R?

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente tabla que he convertido en data.frame:

```
     Peso total   Volumen total Dias       
L1 "410803.384" "675716.98"   "Lunes"    
L2 "327995.018" "549717.029"  "Lunes"    
L3 "246870.322" "407817.491"  "Lunes"    
L4 "231690.05"  "409417.867"  "Lunes"    
L5 "231054.746" "384363.317"  "Lunes"    
M1 "578084.111" "968236.016"  "Martes"   
M2 "456304.612" "760280.61"   "Martes"   
M3 "344529.192" "577821.857"  "Martes"   
M4 "392054.098" "660612.602"  "Martes"   
X1 "511743.765" "893323.429"  "Miércoles"
X2 "337558.75"  "559897.075"  "Miércoles"
X3 "319534.834" "523396.707"  "Miércoles"
X4 "324952.014" "539736.016"  "Miércoles"
J1 "480302.174" "803937.72"   "Jueves"   
J2 "327086.974" "551387.114"  "Jueves"   
J3 "367014.443" "608987.319"  "Jueves"   
J4 "365665.492" "660989.612"  "Jueves"   
V1 "518437.131" "863180.562"  "Viernes"  
V2 "372493.094" "624418.834"  "Viernes"  
V3 "357123.877" "593585.034"  "Viernes"  
V4 "432062.609" "726815.518"  "Viernes
```

Las etiquetas L1, L2, etc, hacen referencia al primer lunes del mes, al segundo, primer martes del mes, etc.
Quiero representar en un gráfico de barras los valores de "Peso total" en función de los días del mes, y lo mismo para "Volumen total".
Pongamos que nos centramos en "Peso total"
Usando el código:

```
ggplot(data = tabla.df) +
        geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Dias, y = `Peso total`,fill=`Peso total`), 
                 stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

Obtengo la siguiente gráfica:
[image: Peso por días]

Ahora bien,me gustaría poner el eje x por orden de los días de la semana: Lunes, Martes, Miércoles,..., y eliminar la leyenda derecha de la gráfica que me indica que valor es cada color, no la necesito.

Y por último, poner una escala en el eje y, para que no aparezcan todos los valores.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada necesitas preparar la información para que sea "amigable" con `ggplot`, ahora no lo es del todo. Veamos:

```
library(tidyverse)

tabla.df %>%
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  separate(id, into=c('d', 'n'), 1) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,as.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(Dias=factor(Dias, 
                     levels = c('Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 
                                'Jueves', 'Viernes'))) %>% 
  select(d,
         n,
         peso_total = `Peso total`, 
         volumen_total=`Volumen total`, 
         Dias) -> plot_data

head(plot_data)
  d n peso_total volumen_total   Dias
1 L 1   410803.4      675717.0  Lunes
2 L 2   327995.0      549717.0  Lunes
3 L 3   246870.3      407817.5  Lunes
4 L 4   231690.0      409417.9  Lunes
5 L 5   231054.7      384363.3  Lunes
6 M 1   578084.1      968236.0 Martes
```

#### ¿Que hemos hecho?

1. Convertimos el `rowname` con los datos `L1, L2, L3 ...` en una verdadera columna, ya que lo vamos a necesitar.
2. Una vez convertido el dato en columna, lo hemos dividido con `separate()` ya que particularmente nos interesa  el número de día.
3. Convertimos las variables que están como texto en tu ejemplo, en numéricas con `mutate_if(is.numeric,as.numeric)`, este es el motivo por lo que en tu gráfica aparecen todos los valores en el eje y.
4. Hemos convertido los nombres de los días en un `factor` con el orden natural de la semana, para que aparezcan ordenados luego.
5. Finalmente como buena práctica, hemos renombrado las columnas con espacio para que sea más sencillo trabajar con ellas.

#### Ahora pasemos a la gráfica

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Dias, y = peso_total, fill = n), 
           stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +
  labs(title = paste("Titulo del gráfico"), 
       subtitle = "Subtitulo" , 
       caption = "Fuente:",
       y = "Peso Total",
       x = ""
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Detalle:

- Cambiamos la estética `fill`, la mapeamos con el número de día, de esta forma cada número de día tendrá un mismo color, en tu ejemplo lo mapeas a la variable `Peso total`, que es una variable continua, y no tiene sentido para una escala que es discreta.
- La leyenda, la eliminamos con `theme(legend.position = "none")`
- Por último, como hemos convertido los valores a numéricos, la escala ahora está más acorde con una numérica, simplemente agregamos `scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)` para hacer mas elegante la impresión de las etiquetas.